# Just-in-time-debugger

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I can't get my Visual Studio 2022 to accept JIT Debugging. When trying to set it up using debug-Options-Just-in-Time, when I click the enable options for the 3 categories I get this message:
[VS JIT Debug error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAlrq.png).

I've reinstalled Visual Studio and I've copied the .vsconfig file from my desktop which does the JIT debug just fine, but that made no difference. I've tried changing some registry values as suggested online to no avail.  Has anybody else had this problem?